# Add class to odd items in dynamic list after more have loaded

Tags: jquery, addclass, css-selectors

I'm trying to add a class to every odd numbered item in a dynamic list. I am doing it on page load with this (which is working):

```
$("#MoreArticles .gridItem:nth-child(odd)").addClass("leftItem");
```

There is a "Show More" button at the bottom, how I can go back through all of the visible items when more are loaded? I've tried simply doing it on click but that doesn't work:

```
$("#LoadMore").click(function() {
   $("#MoreArticles .gridItem:nth-child(odd)").addClass("leftItem");
});
```

I'm guessing I need to run a for each loop or something once more are loaded but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need a `for each loop` unless you want to manipulate a particular item / group of items. Your selector will bring the ones satisfying the condition and apply whatever you're asking it to do.

Comment: How are you getting your new items? `$.ajax`? `$('selector').load()`?

Answer (score 0):

After loading done, do this:

```
$("#MoreArticles .gridItem").removeClass("leftItem");
$("#MoreArticles .gridItem:nth-child(odd)").addClass("leftItem");
```